# Why can CLOS slots be unbound?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slot, clos

It is said, only special variables in Common Lisp can be unbound. For all lexical variables the default value is `nil`. I thought that class slots exist in something like closure, but obviously they don't.

If I define a CLOS slots without `:initform` parameter (in hope that they will be bound to `nil` anyway) and do not supply values when creating instance, I'll get an instance with unbound slots. Why it is so? It's not handy.

Comment: "It is said". Where is that said? "in hope that they will be bound to nil anyway" - why would you hope for something, while the Common Lisp specification says something different? 'hoping' is not really a useful tool when dealing with programming languages. Having unbound slots allows for example to detect whether they are initialized or not.

Comment: @RainerJoswig, You're perfectly right about 'hoping' ;-) It was just a bit of practical exploration of the language features before reading any docs.

Comment: See: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-classes.html

Comment: Not just slots and special variables, but symbols can be unbound as functions.  See [fmakunbound](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fmakun.htm), and [makunbound](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_makunb.htm#makunbound).  Note that a symbol doesn't have to have a special declaration to have a symbol-value, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CLOS instances are not closures**

CLOS instances are usually not implemented as closures. That would be difficult. They are some data structure with something like a vector for the slots. Similar to Common Lisp's structures. A difference between CLOS instances and structures complicates it: it is possible for CLOS instances to change the number of slots at runtime and one can change the class of a CLOS instance at runtime.

**Making sure slots have a `NIL` value**

With some advanced CLOS you can make sure that slots have a NIL value. Note that the functions in the package `CLOS` in my example may be in another package in your CL.

This functions looks over all slots of an instance. If a slot is unbound, it gets set to `NIL`.

```
(defun set-all-unbound-slots (instance &optional (value nil))
  (let ((class (class-of instance)))
    (clos:finalize-inheritance class)
    (loop for slot in (clos:class-slots class)
          for name = (clos:slot-definition-name slot)
          unless (slot-boundp instance name)
          do (setf (slot-value instance name) value))
    instance))
```

We make a *mixin* class:

```
(defclass set-unbound-slots-mixin () ())
```

The fix will be run after initializing the object.

```
(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((i set-unbound-slots-mixin) &rest initargs)
  (set-all-unbound-slots i nil))
```

**Example**:

```
(defclass c1 (set-unbound-slots-mixin)
  ((a :initform 'something)
   b
   c))


CL-USER 1 > (describe (make-instance 'c1))

#<C1 4020092AEB> is a C1
A      SOMETHING
B      NIL
C      NIL
```

Answer (score 8):

It is very handy for things like computing slot values on demand, where the value may sometimes be nil. When accessing an unbound slot, CLOS normally calls the `SLOT-UNBOUND` generic function, which signals an error. Instead of an error, though, you can specialize `SLOT-UNBOUND` to compute and store the value on demand. Subsequent accesses will use the slot value directly, and you can flush the slot "cache" by using `SLOT-MAKUNBOUND`.

You could do this with a sentinel "not-bound" value of some sort, but it's very handy to have the functionality built-in instead.

Example of `slot-unbound` use:

```
(defclass foo ()
  ((bar :accessor bar)
   (baz :accessor baz)))

(defmethod slot-unbound (class (instance foo) slot-name)
  (declare (ignorable class))
  (setf (slot-value instance slot-name) nil))
```

In action:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *foo* (make-instance 'foo))
*FOO*
CL-USER> (bar *foo*)
NIL
CL-USER> (setf (baz *foo*) (not (baz *foo*)))
T
```